# Windows lumia update shows error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

My windows lumia 620 shows error 80096005 whenever i try to install a particular app.It comes only for this one particular app and has been like it for a month.It always stops midway into installation and starts showing an "Attention required.Tap here" message.I have also tried both resets but it remains the same.
Also i cannot find any details about this error code.
.
.
This does not happen while downloading a similar app from the same developer.

Comment: Question is too broad.

Comment: **0x80096005 = TRUST_E_TIME_STAMP = The timestamp signature and/or certificate could not be verified or is malformed.** so the appx has certificate issues

Comment: does anybody know how i can rectify this?the date and time is correct and i have switched off the automatic date setting.

Comment: which app do you try to install? do you have the store link?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/asian-drama-tv/9nblggh5265d is the store link for the app.

Comment: I also can't install the app on my Lumia 950XL. for me with code 0x80073CF9

Comment: The app just suddenly installed from the store today as soon as i clicked install!!!must have been an issue with the app.Thank you for helping.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issues is resolved so no longer relevant and the user has deleted his account. So the question  is dead and should be closed and later deleted.